# <o:commandScript>: reference namespaced JS function name

Tags: javascript, jsf, omnifaces

i am using the omnifaces `<o:commandScript>-tag` to ajax-load data on scroll. currently this fragment works fine, but i wonder, if it is possible to reference a functionname from an external js-file to avoid defining all those scripts in xhtml-files :

products.xhtml:

```
<o:commandScript name="loadNext" actionListener="#{productBean.loadNext}" render="products"/>
       <script type="text/javascript">
             $('.scrollSpy').on('inview.uk.scrollspy', function() { //UIKit scrollspy listener
                loadNext();
            });
       </script>  

       <h:panelGroup id="products">
           <div class="box scrollSpy">
               ...
           </div>
       </h:panelGroup>
```

i am looking for sth like:

products.xhtml:

```
<o:commandScript name="GENERIC.loadNext"
                 actionListener="#{productBean.loadNext}"/>
```

generic.js:

```
 var GENERIC = (function () {

   var my = {};

   my.loadNext = function (){}  //empty

   my.productsLoaded = function (){
    //doSomething
   } 

   $(document).ready(function(){        
      $('.scrollSpy').on('inview.uk.scrollspy', function() { 
             my.loadNext();
      });     
   });      

   return my;

})()
```

but i get

```
[o:commandScript 'name' attribute 'GENERIC.loadNext' does not represent a valid script function name.]
```

while general calls from generic.js work fine, e.g.

`<f:ajax listener="#{productBean.refresh}" render="products" onevent="GENERIC.productsLoaded"/>`

thanks in advance for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requirement was just never taken into account from beginning on. As per [issue 218](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/218) I have fixed it for current 2.3 SNAPSHOT.

The `<o:commandScript>` [won't anymore](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/30ae6db9f796aa83b0ba2e9260ff73468f70cb7a) consider a (correctly placed) period invalid and omit the explicit `var` declaration when the period is present in name.

Comment: just played around with the baked snapshot. that feels really good. 
3..2..1: great thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Just in case, 2.3-RC1 has just been released. Will be in Maven within half a hour.